# Design dynamic grouping of wcf service response attributes based on input request c#

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

Below is a sample format of response and equivalent service contract of my web service looks like.

```
<Players>
 <Player>
     <Name>Sachin</Name>
     <Sport>Cricket</Sport>
     <SportType>Team Game</SportType>
 </Player>
 <Player>
     <Name>Ronaldo</Name>
     <Sport>Football</Sport>
     <SportType>Team Game</SportType>
 </Player>
 <Player>
     <Name>Alfred</Name>
     <Sport>Shooting</Sport>
     <SportType>Individual</SportType>
 </Player>
</Players>
```

Now UI team is asking for new feature where they want grouping logic of different fields in service. For example in input request in newly exposed 'groupBy' field they can send can send field name "Sport" and then they want Player element grouped by "Sport" in response and same is possible for "SportType".

```
<SportTypes>
    <SportType>
        <Type>Team Game</Type>
        <Players>
            <Player>
                <Name>Sachin</Name>
                <Sport>Cricket</Sport>
            </Player>
            <Player>
                <Name>Ronaldo</Name>
                <Sport>Football</Sport>
            </Player>
        </Players>
    </SportType>
    <SportType>
        <Type>Individual</Type>
        <Players>
            <Name>Alfred</Name>
            <Sport>Shooting</Sport>
        </Players>
    </SportType>
</SportTypes>
```

I don't have problem grouping the fields after retrieving them from database but I don't know how can I define service contract for dynamic service response as response structure will change after grouping.For some very odd(maybe stupid) reasons UI team doesn't want to do this grouping so it has to be done in service.
Maybe I am approaching the problem in wrong way.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your datacontract using CollectionDataContract.
For example,

```
 [DataContract]
public  class Player
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Sport { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class SportType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
              // name is the root xml element, itemName is the name of item xml element
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "SportTypes", ItemName = "SportType")]
public class SportTypeCollection : IEnumerable<SportType>
{
    public IList<SportType> SportTypes { get;private set; }
    public IEnumerator<SportType> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.SportTypes.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public SportTypeCollection(params SportType[] sportTypes)
    {
        if (null == sportTypes)
        {
            this.SportTypes = new List<SportType>();
        }
        else
        {
            this.SportTypes = sportTypes;
        }
    }
    public SportTypeCollection()
    {
        this.SportTypes = new List<SportType>();
    }
    public void Add(SportType sportType)
    {
        this.SportTypes.Add(sportType);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.SportTypes.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My test.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SportTypeCollection sportTypes = new SportTypeCollection();
        sportTypes.Add(new SportType { Type = "a", Players = new List<Player> { new Player { Name = "p", Sport = "s" } } });
        sportTypes.Add(new SportType { Type = "b", Players = new List<Player> { new Player { Name = "p", Sport = "v" } } });
        Serialize<SportTypeCollection>(sportTypes, "d:\\message.xml", null, null);
    }
    public static void Serialize<T>(T instance, string fileName, IDataContractSurrogate dataContractSurrogate, params Type[] knownTypes)
    {



        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), knownTypes, int.MaxValue, false, false, dataContractSurrogate);
        using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, instance);
        }
        Process.Start(fileName);
    }
```

The result.

```
<SportTypes xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"           xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceInterface.Models">
<SportType>
<Players>
<Player><Name>p</Name><Sport>s</Sport></Player>
</Players>
<Type>a</Type>
</SportType>

<SportType>
<Players>
<Player><Name>p</Name><Sport>v</Sport></Player>
</Players>
<Type>b</Type>
</SportType>
</SportTypes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it.
Basically I created a generic nested entity which group player entity dynamically based on Player entity.

```
<Group>
   <Type>SportType</Type>
   <Value>TeamGame</Value>
   <GroupSummary/> <!-- Aggregation summary of group -->
   <Group>
       <Type>Sport</Type>
       <Value>Cricket</Value>
       <ListOfEntities>
          <Player1/>
          <Player2/>
       </ListOfEntities>
       <Group/>
    <Group/>
    <ListOfEntites/>
<Group/>
```

Then we can use write simple recursive call for GroupBy, present in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377869/dynamic-linq-nested-group) answer to create nested grouping entities